# Form_with, using a range, output pdf, get instead of post Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My users can add in inventory and then print all the inventory out into lables using a pdf. This part works, now I need to create a form to get the range for items to be printed. The params come over and the all my variables are correct when I check them with byebug.
First issue is that my form wants to post instead of get

No route matches [POST] "/excute_print_tags.pdf"
Now if I add the Route the code runs and no output and I get this in the command line

```
  Inventory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "inventories".* FROM "inventories" WHERE "inventories"."user_id" = $1 AND "inventories"."print_ref" >= $2 AND "inventories"."print_ref" < $3  [["user_id", 1], ["print_ref", 4], ["print_ref", 7]]
  ↳ app/pdfs/inventory_landscape_pdf.rb:18:in `inventory_number'
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2)
Sent data Westcoast Board and Ski_myskiswapinvenotry2020-08-05 14:51:40 -0700.pdf (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 65227ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.6ms | Allocations: 220205)
```

form code inside views/inventories/print_tags.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf") do |form| %>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :print_ref1 %>
        <%= form.number_field :print_ref1, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :print_ref2  %>
        <%= form.number_field :print_ref2, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 md:mb-0 mt-8 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.button class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Then inside the controllers/inventories_contoller

```
 def excute_print_tags
    @print_ref1 = params[:print_ref1]
    @print_ref2 = params[:print_ref2]
    
    @filtered_inventory = @user_inventory.where(print_ref:  @print_ref1...@print_ref2)
    byebug
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = InventoryLandscapePdf.new(@filtered_inventory)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "#{current_user.company}_myskiswapinvenotry#{Time.new}.pdf",
                              type: "application/pdf",
                              disposition: "inline"
      end
    end

  end
```

I have also tried adding the above code to print_tags section of the inventories and calling to itself. Same problem ... I think it has something to do with the way my forms is and it is only allowing it to be sent as a post instead of a get, technically its just a search right? I did try a search for that I found but that didnt solve this issue either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to tell the `form_with` to use get by adding the option: `method: :get`

Comment: I should have said that, but I did try adding in <%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf"), method: :get do |form| %> and same result maybe my syntax is wrong  and tried this as well <%= form_with url: print_tags_path(format: "pdf", method: :get) do |form| %>... I will get a routing error No route matches [POST]  and if I add post to my routes it just runs through but nothing happens

Comment: you're saying that when you used `<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf"), method: :get do |form| %> ` the request is http 'post'

Comment: I am lost to what is causing it. I just been messing with it. No route matches [POST] "/print_tags.pdf"  That is the exact code I have for the form.

Comment: Ok, looks like, maybe I did something wrong with typing it in.. I pasted yours and it is no longer getting that error but no output yet... looks like everything works through the command line but no output on the broswer

Comment: If I run the code that works to print all my labels I get this output on the command line `Inventory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "inventories".* FROM "inventories" WHERE "inventories"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 5]]
  ↳ app/pdfs/inventory_landscape_pdf.rb:19:in `inventory_number'
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1)
Sent data Ski Exchange_myskiswapinvenotry2020-08-05 19:15:06 -0700.pdf (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14344ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms | Allocations: 1493019)`

Comment: and if I submit the form no out put `Inventory Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "inventories".* FROM "inventories" WHERE "inventories"."user_id" = $1 AND "inventories"."print_ref" >= $2 AND "inventories"."print_ref" < $3  [["user_id", 5], ["print_ref", 1], ["print_ref", 10]]
  ↳ app/pdfs/inventory_landscape_pdf.rb:19:in `inventory_number'
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2)
Sent data Ski Exchange_myskiswapinvenotry2020-08-05 19:18:21 -0700.pdf (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25352ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 138779)`

Comment: When you use `<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf"), method: :get do |form| %> ` do you see a :get request in the log? You are showing the database query, but the log should show prior to the query the incoming request.

Comment: `Started GET "/print_tags.pdf?print_ref1=3&print_ref2=10&button=" for ::1 at 2020-08-07 08:46:59 -0700
Processing by InventoriesController#print_tags a PDF` then runs the query and at the end of the command this pops up  
'Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms | Allocations: 94773)`

Comment: `Started GET "/excute_print_tags.pdf?print_ref1=1&print_ref2=10&button=" for ::1 at 2020-08-07 08:59:22 -0700
Processing by InventoriesController#excute_print_tags as PDF`   Sorry this is the output for the excute_print_tags   I had two forms going to try and trouble shoot this

Comment: I can't quite get the full picture. The get request is occurring correctly. But (if your earlier comment still applies) you are not receiving the pdf, even though the log indicates that a pdf was sent. Is this all correct? How is it that a pdf is sent but you are seeing no output? Are you receiving a pdf that is an empty file? Btw the database queries are horrendously slow, but that's for debugging later.

Comment: So there is no output on the screen or download of pdf. I have the pdf code in another part that prints all tags and it works fine. I added byebug in my pdf code and made sure all the params are right and seems like it should work just fine... There is no pdf rendered even though the command line says so

Comment: Is it a permissions thing maybe. I can see every thing getting passed in correctly, infact if I hard code the range and excute_print_tags.pdf I can get the output... Im pretty new to rails so I think its probably something every does and I just dont know

Comment: its processing a get but in my params I see the commit save `Parameters: {"print_ref1"=>"1", "print_ref2"=>"4", "commit"=>"Save "}`

Comment: Small point, when you say "command line" it's not the command line, it's the log file. Rails server outputs (with `tail -f`) the log/development.log file as it's being written. I see nothing that suggests a "permissions thing". The `"commit"=>"Save"` is probably coming from the browser form that triggers the action. When the log indicates a pdf was sent but you are saying that no pdf is rendered, what does the browser dev tools indicate is the response to the get request.

Comment: My form element shows as `data-remote="true" method="get"` looks right and then when I submit the network show `http://localhost:3000/excute_print_tags.pdf?print_ref1=24&print_ref2=39&button=` and status 304 and type xhr  and indicator rails-ujs.js:216... That is off because it will say type PDF  type document.... Weird enough if I double click `http://localhost:3000/excute_print_tags.pdf?print_ref1=24&print_ref2=39&button=` it prints it out like it should have

Comment: I got it! I added local: true to my form... I am not really sure why this worked. Thanks so much for your help, no way would have been able to trouble shoot this on my own. You telling me to look at the browser dev tools help. Much appreciated!  `<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf"), local: true, method: :get do |form| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change this line

```
<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf") do |form| %>
```

To this line

```
<%= form_with url: excute_print_tags_path(format: "pdf"), local: true, method: :get do |form| %>
```

Thanks Les for your help